# Can I use a Mikvah if I am not Jewish?

Tags: gentiles, mikvah-ritual-bath

Although I was baptised as a Christian, I feel a strong sense of connection to Judaism and would like to use the Mikvah. I understand that some people believe there is no point/need because I am not Jewish (nor married) and therefore it has no meaning, however, I would still really like to visit one one day. I feel like I need to fill this spiritual void within myself. Is this permissible?

Comment: You can always go to a natural lake or ocean. Its the same idea from according to Jewish law.

Comment: By "visit" do you mean actually entering the water or just going to see it?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I would like to enter the water but would not do so if it is not allowed.

Comment: The only thing that can happen is if you happen to go into the mikva after accepting upon yourself to keep the laws of the Torah and after having been circumcised, at that point going to the mikva under Rabbinic authority for the purpose of conversion will mean that you will from then on be a Jew. But otherwise you should be fine:)

Comment: Have you ever been to a beach on the ocean?

Answer (score 2):

The most accessible form of mikva is a natural lake or the ocean (assuming you live near a coast). These are considered the ideal mikvaos though most use man-made mikvaos for a variety of other reasons. Natural springs also qualify as mikvaos and in fact purify from things which conventional mikvaos do not. All of these are easily accessible to anyone.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "is it permissible for a non-Jew to go to mikvah," which, AFAICT, was the main question above. "*Is this permissible?*" was the final line of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer this question for all non-Jews but as a Jew by choice who had an Orthodox conversion almost 30 years ago I can say that I was denied the use of one mikvah (after presenting my conversion papers) and encouraged to have (another) Orthodox conversion before requesting to be able to use another one.  So I'm going to say that it depends on the people running the particular mikvah but it is probably not allowed.

Comment: Why did you present your papers to the mikveh even? Why did you tell them you were a convert?

Answer (score -2):

No you should not be visiting the mikvah. Mikvahs are specifically built for the Jewish community (exception being those who wish to join via conversion are required as part of that process). Whilee the idea of mikvah be seem nice it is important that G-d has a designed path for each of us to follow. I would suggest you take a look at this website which talks about the 7 laws given to Noah and his descendants... http://www.noahidenations.com/ also this article... http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380332/jewish/The-Mitzvot-of-Non-Jews.htm

Comment: "Mikvahs are specifically built for the Jewish community" This is certainly not true of all Mikvahs. I don't know why even given that you conclude a non-Jew shouldn't go.

Comment: Dude. Im gonna guess you're not hassidic. Have you never gone to a tish or to get a bracha from a rebbe? If my guess is wrong scratch it, replace it with a different religious denomination and fill in the blank with the practices mentioned with something associated with the new mashal. You give no reason why a person can't choose to experience something outside of his radar. He is not making a shabbos or a holiday for himself.

Comment: @yes AA they are built for the Jewish community.user6591 whether I'm hasidic or not has nothing to do with this question. Can provide me a source that a goy should also use a mikvah if going for yechidus? The reason for Jews to use the mikvah don't apply to non-Jews. Another example of the same concept... in the shulchan aruch it is discussed that someone Jewish who hasn't washed negel vaser from when they woke up if they handle bread that bread should not be eaten, however, there is no such problem for non-Jews. I don't think it is appropriate for someone who isn't Jewish to visit a mikvah.

Comment: @Dude Some are, but [most are not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lakes_of_India). I don't know why that is at all relevant. Do you have any source or reason for the last sentence of your comment or is it just your conjecture?

Comment: while it's true that natural bodies of water can be used as mikva it is clear to anyone not being deliberately obtuse that this was not what I was referring to. Still though I don't think it is appropriate to even use a natural body of water for the purpose of mikva if you aren't Jewish. There are mitzvas for Jews and mitzvas for non Jews and it isn't correct for non-Jews to simply make up their own mitzvas. This is a great resource for more information... http://www.noahidenations.com/ &  http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380332/jewish/The-Mitzvot-of-Non-Jews.htm

Comment: But we hold Tevillah doesn't need Kavana. Why isn't it correct for non-Jews to perform some Mitzvot that Jews are obligated in?

Comment: @Dude, unless you back up your assertions with sources, you are making up your own halachot, which is no better than non-Jews making up their own mitzvot.

Comment: I'm not the one making up halacha. there are mitzvahs for yidden and mitzvahs for b'nei noach. it is a greater chidduch to say it is permissible than not. you provide your sources that clearly say it is okay

Comment: It is a bigger chiddush that non Jews are allowed to go into a pool of rainwater than that they are not? I think you've got it backwards.