# What happens if a non-Jew uses a mikvah?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, mikvah-ritual-bath

If a gentile does a kosher immersion (does tevilah with the preparation, three kosher immersions, and the immersion prayer), which is required for conversion, but did so without the help of a rabbi, does that make them partially converted?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya; interesting question! You might want to take a look at [this related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/can-i-use-a-mikvah-if-i-am-not-jewish). Hope you enjoy MY! :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your question; I removed the part of it that was asked already, and put the information you had in your question title into the body of the question, so it's more accessible. Keep in mind that you can always [edit] your own questions, in case I did something that wasn't to your liking.

Comment: What does "partially converted" even mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe like the status of the givonim

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I don't know what it means.. I am learning about Judaism (I'm not Jewish), but I was wondering what would happen, spiritually, in this situation.

Comment: @doubleAA it could mean a case where someone was circumcised without being immersed, it could refer to a ger toshav, or to a slave, I guess if we're willing to stretch a bit... that last one gives the question extra teeth, IMHO, since the Gemara seems to assume that a slave can free himself by dipping in with intent to convert even against the intent of Beis Din

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/essential-requirements-of-jewish-conversion#comment73814_29609 (cc @DoubleAA)

Comment: Another related question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43665/5323

Comment: Naaman immersed and was not a "convert" and it doesn't appear he was regarded as such. The seven times dunking also seems to imply the acceptance of the seven laws of the Children of Noah.

Answer (score 6):

Maimonides states in the [Laws of Forbidden Sexual Relations](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5113.htm) 13:4, that a non-Jew immerses in a mikveh by himself, it has no effect.
The [Shulchan Aruch](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97) in Y"D 268:3 holds this way as well, provided one did not previously accept the commandments on oneself in front of three Jews.

(See [Be'er Heitiv](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%98%D7%91_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92) that '2' in the S"A may refer to the requirement to at least have witnesses present)